# Windows DC 2012 to 2016 Migration Issues

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, windows-server-2016

I'm having some very weird issues with migrating my 2012 Domain Controller to a new 2016 server. Most articles I have read state that all I need to do a set up the 2016 server as a Domain Controller and move the FSMO roles... then when all looks good, I can remove the Domain Controller on 2012. Well this certainly was not the case for me. DCDiag on the 2016 server is showing this:

```
Starting test: Advertising
   Warning: DsGetDcName returned information for \\ds1.dir
   reach DS2.
   SERVER IS NOT RESPONDING or IS NOT CONSIDERED SUITABLE.
   ......................... DS2 failed test Advertising

Starting test: NetLogons
   Unable to connect to the NETLOGON share! (\\DS2\netlog
   [DS2] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with er
   ......................... DS2 failed test NetLogons
```

I found the following article that seems like it would help my case: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ziggy/2013/08/20/sysvol-on-newly-promoted-dc-is-not-synchronising-but-replication-looks-ok/

I am currently trying to add the Administrators group to the "Default Domain Policy", which is explained in this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2567421/dfsr-sysvol-fails-to-migrate-or-replicate,-sysvol-not-shared,-event-ids-8028-or-6016

When I add the group, GPMC returns this error: "the system cannot find the path specified"

I'm really not sure what to do from here. I had to remove DNS from the 2012 server because it was giving issues with my new 2016 DC. I cannot demote the 2012 DC because it is telling me it cannot contact the other DC. I'm afraid to touch anything in fear of losing my whole directory.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: If you've removed DNS from your only functioning DC then you're probably in a spot of trouble. What are your DNS settings? You should have your new DC pointing at your functioning DC to start with, then to itself once it's functional.

Comment: Well DNS is running on the 2016 sever and seems to be functional. I have bind set up to forward any DNS requests for directory.Company.com to the 2016 server. We are a pure Mac shop so I'm not worried about anything but my active directory users and groups. Would it help if I added DNS back to the 2012 server?

Comment: I should also mention that everything appears to be working fine as far as my clients go... Despite having weird issues with both domain controllers.

Comment: DNS is fairly fundamental to the correct operation of a domain controller, so you should definitely add it back on, at least until after you have demoted it.

Comment: Ok DNS has been reinstalled on Server 2012 and it looks like it has all my domain DNS stuff in it. Both servers are pointing to the 2016 server for their DNS. What should I do now?

Comment: Is it normal that anything that would be using the 2012 server for DNS would not be able to authenticate? The 2016 is the primary DNS server.

Comment: Nope, not normal. Any correctly functioning DC should be able to authenticate a user - that's it's role. Perhaps DNS was still replicating? Did you get anywhere with the technet article?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix all my issues by manually sharing my SYSVOL folder and then copying the SYSVOL folder from my 2012 DC to my 2016 DC. I then edited the GP to include the Administrators group. Then I edited this registry key:

```
Key  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\parameters
Value SysvolReady = 1
```

Then ran "gpupdate force" in powershell and everything was happy.